# How to get SQL to get ID that's start with 'P' and followed by '11' numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

The column can only accept ID that starts with P and followed by 11 numbers for example P12345678901
It needs to accept in that particular order.
Can I use LIKE to solve the problem in the CREATE TABLE? or can I actually just use CHECK constraint to somehow get it works.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLENAME (
ID VARCHAR(12) CHECK (ID = 'P[0-9]{11}')
```

Comment: Use `char(12)` or `varchar` as datatype

Comment: What rdbms are you working with? Do you really need the `p` prefix or can you store only the numbers?

Comment: It needs to end with numbers. and starts with P

Comment: @ZoharPeled MySQL

Comment: You can build the logic into the INSERT itself and/or handle such logic in application code

Answer (score 4):

You can use `regexp_like()`.

```
CREATE TABLE elbat
             (id varchar(12),
              CHECK (regexp_like(id, '^P[0-9]{11}$', 'c')));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=605abd1211386ffcced9197f68025e1a)

But note that check constraints only work in version 8+. In lower versions they are parsed without error or warning when in a `CREATE TABLE` statement but not enforced later on.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that if the `P` prefix is constant you might want to simply save the numbers in an `int` column and add the `p` just for display purposes - as a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html):

```
CREATE TABLE table (
  ActualData int, 
  DataForDisplay AS (CONCAT('P', RIGHT((CONCAT('0000000000', ActualData), 11)
);
```

Comment: This doesn't really stop the wrong stuff from being inserted

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not a MySql guy, my experience is mostly with MS Sql, but as far as I know, `int` is a 32 bit integer value which means up to 11 digits - so how can wrong stuff be inserted like this?

Comment: You're confusing storage with display. Just because it 'looks' valid, it doesn't mean it is.

Comment: @strawberry I disagree. If anything, I'm breaking the connection between the display and the storage. Just because the OP wants `P` before an all-digits value, doesn't mean that's what should be stored. If anything, my suggestion allows less values that the other answer.